# Curve resolution limited

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

The curve resolution is limited, and I would like it to be higher. Usually, you can manually increase this, but in this case, it just resets. Is there any way to remove this limitation?

[image]

Comment: If you're talking about the Resolution Render U, it is limited at 64 with the mouse cursor but you can type a higher value

Comment: @moonboots no - I tried that already. For some reason it didn't work and simply reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got a special reason not to use an *Object* bevel profile?

[image]

Comment: I've tried to watch a tutorial on this, and this is exactly what the tutorial did. However, I had a LOT of trouble getting this to work, and eventually gave up. No matter how I scaled or rotated in object mod,e, nothing happned. I could not apply any transform in edit mode.

Comment: @Sid I'll add more detail, tomorrow.. whatever's not working for you, I'm sure it's one of those 'very simple' things that are somehow easy to miss .

Comment: Sounds good! I did eventually fix this by simply rotating in object mode, and then applying rotation. Don't know why this didn't work, but I tried in a blank file and it worked fine, so I really don't know what changed.

Answer (score 3):

Your screen capture implies that you're talking about the *Bevel* Resolution:

[image: Bevel resolution]

rather than the *Render U* Resolution mentioned in the comments.

The hard limit for Bevel Resolution *is* 32 and you would have to modify and recompile Blender to change it, as the limit is related to data structures in the C code.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I definitely was talking about the bevel resolution. Any Idea how I should go about changing the source code/where it would be?

Comment: The Blender foundation has [Getting Started Advice for Developers](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Developer_Intro/Advice) as an introduction to how to go about changing the code.  You can find a copy of the code on their [github account](https://github.com/blender/blender). [curve_bevel.c](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/curve_bevel.c) is probably a good place to start looking.